# Celery runs locally but not in production

Tags: django, kubernetes, redis, scrapy, celery

My app involves Django, Celery, Redis, and Scrapy.

Locally, I fire up Django (`python manage.py runserver`) and celery (`celery -A web_app worker`). Then, I trigger a command which runs a scrapy webcrawler (via CrawlerRunner), retrieves some information, and makes additional async calls which are pushed to my task queue. This all works fine.

However, when I run celery via Kubernetes (called the same way `celery -A web_app worker`), my tasks stop running after the scrapy task finished. The worker won't execute any additional tasks unless I restart it.

Ideas?

What's going on under the hood when I run celery with the same command in Kubernetes versus when I run it locally?

Comment: How do you dockerized your application? Are you running locally in docker?

Comment: @AliTou No, not dockerized. So, they're different environments completely. I dockerize it and run it in a Kubernetes cluster pushed to AWS via KOPS.

Comment: @AliTou The scraper runs fine. As do some of the tasks associated with it. But, seemingly, when the scraper finishes in production. The remaining tasks are neither received, not executed until the worker is restarted.

Comment: @AliTou I'm not sure the most efficient way to debug this. It seems the scrapy crawl is still an active task; so, potentially preventing other tasks from being run? Other tasks are triggered via signals as a result of it. That might be a bad pattern and lead to these conditions.